# What's the meaning of 'pusher'?

Tags: meaning

> And no matter what the fancy-product ***pushers*** may have you believe, there's nothing you can do to prevent this.

This is about  striae gravidarum during pregnancy. I searched the Internet and it says pusher means someone who tries to make someone to buy something. What does it mean above? Please tell me.

Comment: it means exactly what you said. Someone trying to get you to buy fancy products.

Comment: The word is used metaphorically, based in the word "pusher" in "drug pusher" -- someone who "pushes" you to buy illicit stuff.  In this case the product is presumably not illicit, but the way it's promoted makes one question the integrity of the salesmen.

Comment: What are all these pregnancy-related documents that you're reading and are confusing you?

Comment: It means there are people who sell products that they claim will relieve the symptoms of striae gravidarum, but you they don't really work.

Comment: FYI, "striae gravidarum" means "stretch marks", although presumably specific to those developed from pregnancy.

Answer (score 3):

["Pusher"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pusher) is a pejorative most often associated with those who sell illegal drugs, especially those which are addictive.

> (informal) A person who sells illegal drugs: "an underworld of thugs, drug pushers, and thieves" (Oxford English Dictionary)

In this sentence the author equates merchants who aggressively market dubious cures for stretch marks to "pushers" of other drugs.  The implication is that those who sell these substances are no better than criminals who exploit others for profit.